# Use an image in more than one field in a FCE

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I created two fields in templavoila and want to access the image url (data object) from the other field.

field1 - typoscript - type: image:

```
10 = IMG_RESOURCE
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0
10.file.maxH = 300
```

field2 - typoscript:

```
10 = IMG_RESOURCE
10.file.import.data = field1
```

But id doesn't work. I tried various variations of the above, but nothing works :(

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks,

Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object should be IMAGE type instead of IMG_RESOURCE.
And on the field2 typoscript:

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file.import.field = field1
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.listNum = 0
10.file.maxH = 300
```

This should display the image uploaded on the field type image "field1".
Hope this helps!
Cornelia